# Using LIKE in CASE statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

how to use `LIKE` in `CASE` statement, I have got this example script but does not work. I use MS SQL 2008

```
DECLARE
    @DataBaseName sysname,
    @Message char(255)

SET @DataBaseName = 'DBa';

SET @Message =
    CASE @DataBaseName 
        WHEN LIKE 'DBa'
        THEN 'Valid name'
    ELSE 'INVALID name'
    END
Print @Message;
```

Comment: Do you want to do a case-insensitive comparison or a 'DBa*'? In the last case you need to add a '%' at the end...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use `LIKE` I think you need to use this form of the `CASE` statement (the "searched" form). The "simple" form [allows only an equality check](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

```
SET @Message =
    CASE  
        WHEN @DataBaseName LIKE 'DBa' /*As Yves points out in the comments
                                        should this be 
        WHEN @DataBaseName LIKE 'DBa%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS  */
        THEN 'Valid name'
    ELSE 'INVALID name'
    END
```